# Find max uninterrupted interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I can find max uninterrupted interval in column?

Example

```
ID    Result
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5       5
6       6
10
11
12
```

Comment: can you be more specific? what if there are multiple such id sequences..what should the output be?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala should be selected MAX uninterrupted id sequence

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()`.  Here is a simple way to get the first and lsat values:

```
select top (1) with ties min(id), max(id)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (id - seqnum)
order by count(*) desc;
```

To get the actual original rows requires another level of window functions:

```
select top (1) with ties
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id - seqnum) as cnt
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
order by cnt desc, id;
```